# Sharepoint list last modified date

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, javascript, splistitem

I use this code to get the date of the last edit of a certain list.
Now I want to loop through the listitems and identify the item that was changed last, so i.e. that has the same date as the lastItemModifiedDate()

How you I do this?

Anyone?

```
ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(Initializeall, 'sp.js');
 function Initializeall()
{

 var ctx = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
 var web = ctx.get_web();
 var lists = web.get_lists();
 var list = lists.getByTitle("Sample");
ctx.load(list, "LastItemModifiedDate");
ctx.executeQueryAsync(
function() {
    var lastmodified = list.get_lastItemModifiedDate();
alert(lastmodified);
},
function() {}
);
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The item that was changed last may not have the same date as the lastItemModifiedDate(). For example, the item was last changed in 9/20, you added a column to the list in 9/25, the lastItemModifiedDate() would be 9/25. They are different.

The SP.List.lastItemModifiedDate property gets a value that specifies the last time a list item, field, or property of the list was modified. So if you just changed the list description or add a column to the list, the lastItemModifiedDate() would get updated. Reference: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/sharepoint-visio/jj244925(v=office.15)

And to identify the item that was changed last, you could use CAML query with jsom. For example:

```
var list = web.get_lists().getByTitle("List1");
var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
camlQuery.set_viewXml("<View><Query><OrderBy><FieldRef Name='Modified' Ascending='FALSE' /></OrderBy></Query></View>");
items=list.getItems(camlQuery);
clientContext.load(items);
```